# Prononciation de docteure ?

Tags: prononciation, accents-régionaux

Selon Wiki

> (...) Il est à noter que c’est (c-à-d docteure) un néologisme qui ne change pas la
>   prononciation (**sauf dans le sud de la France**) mais seulement
>   l’orthographe.

Comment alors *docteure* se prononce dans le sud de la France ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans le sud de la France, les *e* [finals](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/final) habituellement muets ailleurs sont souvent prononcés comme un [œ] doux, sans toutefois de déplacement de l'accent tonique.

Il est parfois retranscrit et grossi caricaturalement en terminant le mot par *eu* ou *euh*, comme on peut le voir dans la [réponse méprisante de Jean-Luc Mélenchon](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/politique/melenchon/video-agace-par-une-question-jean-luc-melenchon-imite-l-accent-toulousain-d-une-journaliste_2990879.html) à une journaliste toulousaine :

> Et alors, qu'esse-que-ça-veut-direu ?

voire

> Et alors, qu'esseuh-que ça veut direuh ?

Note: On ne peut pas vraiment dire que ce *e* final change la prononciation dans le sud de la France car, comme l'a commenté @Destal, *docteur* au masculin y est en général aussi déjà prononcé avec un *E* final.

Comment: Mais ne prononcent-ils pas "docteur" avec ce "euh" final également ?

Comment: @Destal Pas faux, il n'y a en effet souvent pas de différence entre *docteur* et *docteure*, ou elle est très atténuée, comme par exemple entre *(un) fil* et *(une) file*. Ce n'est pas tout à fait équivalent à un *euh* final car l'accentuation du mot est plus forte qu'en français non méridional et reste sur la même syllabe (teur), ce qui n'est pas possible en français "parisien" quand une autre syllabe suit.

Comment: `e finales` ou `e finaux` mais pas `e finals` ;-)

Comment: @Toto [Finals](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/final) passe [un peu de mode](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=finaux%2C+finals&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinaux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinals%3B%2Cc0), mais n'est certainement pas incorrect.

Comment: Certes, mais cela m'écorche un peu les oreilles (voire les yeux en l'occurrence)

Comment: @Toto C'est le contraire pour moi. On m'a enseigné ce pluriel et *finaux* m'évoque trop *finauds* pour que je l'utilise...

Comment: Ce débat sur finals/finaux est asez intéressant. Je me rend compte que de mon côté j'aurais tendance à employer les 2. Quand le "final" est dans une expression figée je trouve que "finals" permet à l'oral de garder la même prononciation de cette expression, mais quand il est utilisé seul j'aurais tendance à dire "finaux": "le résultat final/les résultats finaux" , mais "un point final/des points finals"

Comment: @LaurentS. *"On connaît l'histoire du directeur de zoo qui écrit à son fournisseur : Envoyez-moi deux chacals. Il se ravise, jette son premier courrier et écrit à nouveau : Envoyez-moi deux chacaux. Finalement, il jette aussi la seconde lettre et écrit : Envoyez-moi un chacal. Il signe et rajoute en-dessous : PS - Envoyez m'en plutôt deux. [Le bon pluriel est « chacals »] . :)"* https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/finals-finaux-pluriel-de-final.455912/

Comment: @Dimitris J'adore cette blague et j'y ai justement pensé ce matin en lisant ceci :-)